# MVC 5 Multiple Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, viewcontroller

Is it possible to have multiple @Model functions within one page?

I have a Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml page which has the following code to pull the navigation from an SQL Server 2012 database:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.navigation_V>

<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <li>@Html.MenuItem(item.title_TV, item.url_TV, "Home")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This works fine on all views within the Views/Home folder, however the View/Accounts/Login.cshtml file has the following code:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.LoginViewModel
```

Now I get the following error when trying to view the Account/Login page:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication1.navigation_V]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.Models.LoginViewModel'.

When writing the code I am not getting any red underline squiggles, the error only fires when trying to access the Account/Login page. This navigation function must be viewable on all pages, what I'm dreading next is actually getting the rest of the page content from the database in to these pages.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

For further information I have included more code.

```
WebApplication1Entities.cs

using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace WebApplication1
{    
    public partial class WebApplication1Entities : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication1Entities()
            : base("name=WebApplication1Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<navigation_V> navigation_V { get; set; }
    }
}   

navigation_V.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class navigation_V
    {
        public int navigation_ID { get; set; }
        public string title_TV { get; set; }
        public string url_TV { get; set; }
    }
}

Controllers/HomeController.cs:

public static class MenuExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string text,
        string action,
        string controller
    )
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
}

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.navigation_V.ToList());
        }
    }
}

Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.navigation_V>

<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <li>@Html.MenuItem(item.title_TV, item.url_TV, "Home")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

I hope this make things a little clearer.

Comment: Not possible. But you can use an interface instead of a class on the layout page, and make models of inner pages implement that interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, each page needs to return multiple data sets, could you please provide a brief example?

Comment: Where do you create and pass the instance of `List<navigation_V>`? Post code.

Comment: Please see my amended post.

Comment: ok, but what code do you have in the `AccountController.Login` method? Anyway I will post an answer now and will update it if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rendering navigation IEnumerable in layout you can write child action in your Home controller like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Navigation()
{
    var navigationModel = ..
    // your code to retrieve IEnumerable<WebApplication1.navigation_V>
    // from DB

    return View(navigationModel);
}
```

View for this action is Views/Home/Navigation.cshtml:

```
@{ Layout = null; } // preventing recursive rendering
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.navigation_V>

<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <li>@Html.MenuItem(item.title_TV, item.url_TV, "Home")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

And code for _layout.cshtml, replace your old navigation code with this one:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Navigation", "Home"); }
```

Comment: I have just edited my post to include further code, but not sure how to restructure.

Comment: Many thanks your code worked, the only issue I've noticed is the active class is not being applied in the MenuItem function, I think this maybe because the code now resides in the View/Navigation.cshtml page so is not being called in the _Layout.cshtml so is not detecting the correct URL, could you please suggest how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Modified the MenuExtensions class to use var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"); var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

All is well, thank you again :-)